# had an error running java program using Mathematica libraries

Tags: java, dll, jvm, wolfram-mathematica

I was trying to do some diffrential equations calculation using Mathematica libraries. I used jlink to link java with Mathematica. Somehow I can't get the program running, I think something is wrong with the `JLinkNativeLibrary.dll` or idk. here are my program code, error and logs, they are all here:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffb99d514d2, pid=8024, tid=0x0000000000003f30
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_341-b10) (build 1.8.0_341-b10)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.341-b10 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [JLinkNativeLibrary.dll+0x114d2]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# E:\idea_pro\DE-Solutions\hs_err_pid8024.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

Process finished with exit code 1
```

```
import com.wolfram.jlink.*;

public class SolveDE {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //String ode = "DSolve[y'[x] == -(x - 3 y[x]^2)/(x*y[x]), y, x]";
        String ode1 = "odes=NDSolve[{y'[t] == y[t] + t,y[0]==1}, y, {t,0,10000}]";        
        double a1 = ODESolve(ode1 ,2,"y");
        System.out.println(a1);

        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

        String ode2 = "odes=NDSolve[{y''[x] + Sin[y[x]] y[x] == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 30}]";   
        double a2 = ODESolve(ode2,5.2,"y");
        System.out.println(a2);

        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

        String ode3 = "odes=NDSolve[{y'[t]  == 3*y[t] - 2*z[t], z'[t] == 2*y[t]-z[t], z[0] == 2, y[0] == 1}, {y,z}, {t, 0, 10}]";  
        double a3 = ODESolve(ode3,4,"y");
        System.out.println(a3);
    }

    public static double ODESolve(String ode, double key,String required_property) {
        KernelLink mathlink = null;

        try {
   
            mathlink = MathLinkFactory.createKernelLink("-linkmode launch -linkname 'E:\\Mathematica_11.3\\MathKernel'");
        } catch (MathLinkException e) {
            System.out.println("Fatal error opening link: " + e.getMessage());
            return -1;
        }

        try {
            mathlink.discardAnswer();
            mathlink.evaluateToInputForm(ode, 0);
            String value = mathlink.evaluateToOutputForm(""+required_property+"[" + key + "]/.odes",0);
            mathlink.evaluate(""+required_property+"[" + key + "]/.odes");
            mathlink.waitForAnswer();      


            String ans_0 = value.substring(1,value.length()-1);
            double ans =Double.parseDouble(ans_0);
            return ans;

        } catch (MathLinkException e) {
            System.out.println("MathLinkException occurred: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            mathlink.close();
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffb99d514d2, pid=8024, tid=0x0000000000003f30
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_341-b10) (build 1.8.0_341-b10)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.341-b10 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [JLinkNativeLibrary.dll+0x114d2]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000001fbd6375000):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=16176, stack(0x000000eeafa00000,0x000000eeafb00000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0xfffffffff36b3570

Registers:
RAX=0x00007ffb99d42ee0, RBX=0xfffffffff36b3220, RCX=0xfffffffff36b3220, RDX=0x0000000000000000
RSP=0x000000eeafaff3b0, RBP=0x000000eeafaff480, RSI=0x00000000000009c8, RDI=0x0000000000000000
R8 =0xfffffffff36b3220, R9 =0x0000000000000004, R10=0x000001fbd7d699c2, R11=0x000000006043a790
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x000001fbf0a4f208, R14=0x0000000000000000, R15=0x000001fbd6375000
RIP=0x00007ffb99d514d2, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010282

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000eeafaff3b0)
0x000000eeafaff3b0:   000001fbf0a4f208 000001fbd6375000
0x000000eeafaff3c0:   000001fbd7d58180 00000000000009c8
0x000000eeafaff3d0:   000000eeafaff4a8 00007ffb99d42ef3
0x000000eeafaff3e0:   00000000000009c8 000001fbf0a4f208
0x000000eeafaff3f0:   000001fbd7d58180 000001fbf0a4f208
0x000000eeafaff400:   000001fbd7d58180 000001fbd7d699ee
0x000000eeafaff410:   000001fbf0a4f208 000000eeafaff480
0x000000eeafaff420:   00000000000009c8 000001fbd6375000
0x000000eeafaff430:   000000eeafaff530 000001fbd7d696a2
0x000000eeafaff440:   000000eeafaff440 000001fbf0a4f208
0x000000eeafaff450:   000000eeafaff4a8 000001fbf0a4faf8
0x000000eeafaff460:   0000000000000000 000001fbf0a4f208
0x000000eeafaff470:   0000000000000000 000000eeafaff4a0
0x000000eeafaff480:   000000eeafaff500 000001fbd7d583fd
0x000000eeafaff490:   000000076b464fd8 000001fbd7d62df8
0x000000eeafaff4a0:   fffffffff36b3220 000000076b469fd0 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007ffb99d514d2)
0x00007ffb99d514b2:   5c 24 10 48 89 7c 24 18 41 56 48 83 ec 20 33 ff
0x00007ffb99d514c2:   4c 8b f2 48 8b d9 48 85 c9 74 7e 48 89 74 24 30
0x00007ffb99d514d2:   40 38 b9 50 03 00 00 74 0d 48 8b 89 30 03 00 00
0x00007ffb99d514e2:   48 8b 01 ff 50 10 40 38 bb 50 03 00 00 74 0d 48 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x00007ffb99d42ee0 is an unknown value
RBX=0xfffffffff36b3220 is an unknown value
RCX=0xfffffffff36b3220 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000eeafaff3b0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000001fbd6375000
RBP=0x000000eeafaff480 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000001fbd6375000
RSI=0x00000000000009c8 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R8 =0xfffffffff36b3220 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000000004 is an unknown value
R10=0x000001fbd7d699c2 is at code_begin+962 in an Interpreter codelet
method entry point (kind = native)  [0x000001fbd7d69600, 0x000001fbd7d6a0a0]  2720 bytes
R11=0x000000006043a790 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13={method} {0x000001fbf0a4f210} 'MLSetMessageHandler' '(J)V' in 'com/wolfram/jlink/NativeLink'
R14=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R15=0x000001fbd6375000 is a thread


Stack: [0x000000eeafa00000,0x000000eeafb00000],  sp=0x000000eeafaff3b0,  free space=1020k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [JLinkNativeLibrary.dll+0x114d2]
C  [JLinkNativeLibrary.dll+0x2ef3]
C  0x000001fbd7d699ee

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.wolfram.jlink.NativeLink.MLSetMessageHandler(J)V+0
j  com.wolfram.jlink.NativeLink.addMessageHandler(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)Z+18
j  com.wolfram.jlink.WrappedKernelLink.addMessageHandler(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)Z+7
j  com.wolfram.jlink.WrappedKernelLink.<init>(Lcom/wolfram/jlink/MathLink;)V+23
j  com.wolfram.jlink.MathLinkFactory.createKernelLink0(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/wolfram/jlink/KernelLink;+336
j  com.wolfram.jlink.MathLinkFactory.createKernelLink(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/wolfram/jlink/KernelLink;+2
j  SolveDE.ODESolve(Ljava/lang/String;DLjava/lang/String;)D+5
j  SolveDE.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+9
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x000001fbf3608000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9100, stack(0x000000eeb0f00000,0x000000eeb1000000)]
  0x000001fbf355f000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2816, stack(0x000000eeb0e00000,0x000000eeb0f00000)]
  0x000001fbf355d800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14400, stack(0x000000eeb0d00000,0x000000eeb0e00000)]
  0x000001fbf355a800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8800, stack(0x000000eeb0c00000,0x000000eeb0d00000)]
  0x000001fbf3558000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=17340, stack(0x000000eeb0b00000,0x000000eeb0c00000)]
  0x000001fbf3541800 JavaThread "Monitor Ctrl-Break" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=10008, stack(0x000000eeb0a00000,0x000000eeb0b00000)]
  0x000001fbf3512800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14484, stack(0x000000eeb0900000,0x000000eeb0a00000)]
  0x000001fbf10de800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12952, stack(0x000000eeb0800000,0x000000eeb0900000)]
  0x000001fbf10c3000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7448, stack(0x000000eeb0700000,0x000000eeb0800000)]
  0x000001fbf10bc000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7440, stack(0x000000eeb0600000,0x000000eeb0700000)]
=>0x000001fbd6375000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=16176, stack(0x000000eeafa00000,0x000000eeafb00000)]

Other Threads:
  0x000001fbf1094000 VMThread [stack: 0x000000eeb0500000,0x000000eeb0600000] [id=16792]
  0x000001fbf364a000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x000000eeb1000000,0x000000eeb1100000] [id=9036]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

heap address: 0x00000006c1200000, size: 4078 MB, Compressed Oops mode: Zero based, Oop shift amount: 3
Narrow klass base: 0x0000000000000000, Narrow klass shift: 3
Compressed class space size: 1073741824 Address: 0x00000007c0000000

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 76288K, used 7872K [0x000000076b100000, 0x0000000770600000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 65536K, 12% used [0x000000076b100000,0x000000076b8b0200,0x000000076f100000)
  from space 10752K, 0% used [0x000000076fb80000,0x000000076fb80000,0x0000000770600000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x000000076f100000,0x000000076f100000,0x000000076fb80000)
 ParOldGen       total 175104K, used 0K [0x00000006c1200000, 0x00000006cbd00000, 0x000000076b100000)
  object space 175104K, 0% used [0x00000006c1200000,0x00000006c1200000,0x00000006cbd00000)
 Metaspace       used 4473K, capacity 4864K, committed 5120K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 478K, capacity 496K, committed 512K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x000001fbe7110000,0x000001fbe7910000] byte_map_base: 0x000001fbe3b07000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x00000000609f9030
 Begin Bits: [0x000001fbe7e60000, 0x000001fbebe18000)
 End Bits:   [0x000001fbebe18000, 0x000001fbefdd0000)

Polling page: 0x000001fbd7d20000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=1365Kb max_used=1365Kb free=244394Kb
 bounds [0x000001fbd7d50000, 0x000001fbd7fc0000, 0x000001fbe6d50000]
 total_blobs=401 nmethods=124 adapters=191
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 2.316 Thread 0x000001fbf355f000  121       3       java.util.HashMap::getNode (148 bytes)
Event: 2.316 Thread 0x000001fbf355f000 nmethod 121 0x000001fbd7ea3b90 code [0x000001fbd7ea3d60, 0x000001fbd7ea4710]
Event: 2.316 Thread 0x000001fbf355f000  119       3       sun.misc.VM::allowArraySyntax (4 bytes)
Event: 2.316 Thread 0x000001fbf355f000 nmethod 119 0x000001fbd7ea3890 code [0x000001fbd7ea39e0, 0x000001fbd7ea3b38]
Event: 2.316 Thread 0x000001fbf355f000  122       3       java.util.HashMap::get (23 bytes)
Event: 2.316 Thread 0x000001fbf355f000 nmethod 122 0x000001fbd7ea3190 code [0x000001fbd7ea3320, 0x000001fbd7ea3740]
Event: 2.316 Thread 0x000001fbf355f000  123       3       java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node::<init> (26 bytes)
Event: 2.317 Thread 0x000001fbf355f000 nmethod 123 0x000001fbd7ea2d50 code [0x000001fbd7ea2ea0, 0x000001fbd7ea30b8]
Event: 2.317 Thread 0x000001fbf355f000  124       3       java.lang.String::indexOf (25 bytes)
Event: 2.317 Thread 0x000001fbf355f000 nmethod 124 0x000001fbd7ea2910 code [0x000001fbd7ea2a80, 0x000001fbd7ea2c30]

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Classes redefined (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (6 events):
Event: 0.017 Thread 0x000001fbd6375000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BII)Ljava/lang/Class; name or signature does not match> (0x000000076b107cc8) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-x64-cygwin\jdk8u341\2692\hotsp
Event: 0.017 Thread 0x000001fbd6375000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.prefetchRead(Ljava/lang/Object;J)V name or signature does not match> (0x000000076b107fb0) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-x64-cygwin\jdk8u341\2692\hotspot\src\share\vm\pr
Event: 0.074 Thread 0x000001fbd6375000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x000000076b4928a8) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-x64-cygwin\jdk8u341\2692\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1523]
Event: 0.074 Thread 0x000001fbd6375000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x000000076b492ab8) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-x64-cygwin\jdk8u341\2692\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1523]
Event: 0.075 Thread 0x000001fbd6375000 Exception <a 'java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError'> (0x000000076b498e88) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-x64-cygwin\jdk8u341\2692\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 4125]
Event: 0.075 Thread 0x000001fbd6375000 Exception <a 'java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError'> (0x000000076b498e88) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-x64-cygwin\jdk8u341\2692\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 710]

Events (10 events):
Event: 2.315 loading class com/wolfram/jlink/JLinkClassLoaderHelper
Event: 2.315 loading class com/wolfram/jlink/JLinkClassLoaderHelper done
Event: 2.316 loading class com/wolfram/jlink/InstanceCollection
Event: 2.316 loading class com/wolfram/jlink/InstanceCollection done
Event: 2.316 loading class java/util/Collections$SynchronizedMap
Event: 2.316 loading class java/util/Collections$SynchronizedMap done
Event: 2.316 loading class com/wolfram/jlink/Expr
Event: 2.316 loading class com/wolfram/jlink/Expr done
Event: 2.317 loading class java/util/Vector$1
Event: 2.317 loading class java/util/Vector$1 done


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff7eab60000 - 0x00007ff7eaba7000     E:\jdk8\bin\java.exe
0x00007ffbd64b0000 - 0x00007ffbd66a8000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007ffbd4770000 - 0x00007ffbd482d000     C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007ffbd3c40000 - 0x00007ffbd3f0e000     C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007ffbd48f0000 - 0x00007ffbd499e000     C:\Windows\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007ffbd4510000 - 0x00007ffbd45ae000     C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007ffbd4e20000 - 0x00007ffbd4ebc000     C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll
0x00007ffbd4640000 - 0x00007ffbd4765000     C:\Windows\System32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007ffbd57f0000 - 0x00007ffbd5990000     C:\Windows\System32\USER32.dll
0x00007ffbd44e0000 - 0x00007ffbd4502000     C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll
0x00007ffbd5630000 - 0x00007ffbd565a000     C:\Windows\System32\GDI32.dll
0x00007ffbd40a0000 - 0x00007ffbd41ab000     C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll
0x00007ffbd4410000 - 0x00007ffbd44ad000     C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll
0x00007ffbd4310000 - 0x00007ffbd4410000     C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll
0x00007ffbbf390000 - 0x00007ffbbf62a000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.19041.1110_none_60b5254171f9507e\COMCTL32.dll
0x00007ffbd6170000 - 0x00007ffbd61a0000     C:\Windows\System32\IMM32.DLL
0x00007ffbcac70000 - 0x00007ffbcac85000     E:\jdk8\jre\bin\vcruntime140.dll
0x00007ffbb3460000 - 0x00007ffbb34fb000     E:\jdk8\jre\bin\msvcp140.dll
0x0000000060210000 - 0x0000000060a71000     E:\jdk8\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007ffbd49a0000 - 0x00007ffbd49a8000     C:\Windows\System32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007ffbb9b70000 - 0x00007ffbb9b79000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007ffbcb7a0000 - 0x00007ffbcb7c7000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x00007ffbcdfe0000 - 0x00007ffbcdfea000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x00007ffbd59f0000 - 0x00007ffbd5a5b000     C:\Windows\System32\WS2_32.dll
0x00007ffbd1af0000 - 0x00007ffbd1b02000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\kernel.appcore.dll
0x00007ffbd1330000 - 0x00007ffbd1340000     E:\jdk8\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x00007ffbcac40000 - 0x00007ffbcac6b000     E:\jdk8\jre\bin\java.dll
0x00007ffbbe710000 - 0x00007ffbbe740000     E:\jdk8\jre\bin\instrument.dll
0x00007ffbc7280000 - 0x00007ffbc7298000     E:\jdk8\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x00007ffbd4ed0000 - 0x00007ffbd5614000     C:\Windows\System32\SHELL32.dll
0x00007ffbd1cf0000 - 0x00007ffbd2484000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\windows.storage.dll
0x00007ffbd5df0000 - 0x00007ffbd6144000     C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll
0x00007ffbd3630000 - 0x00007ffbd3660000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\Wldp.dll
0x00007ffbd5660000 - 0x00007ffbd570d000     C:\Windows\System32\SHCORE.dll
0x00007ffbd5710000 - 0x00007ffbd5765000     C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll
0x00007ffbd3b10000 - 0x00007ffbd3b2f000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\profapi.dll
0x00007ffbb5430000 - 0x00007ffbb544a000     E:\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.2\bin\breakgen64.dll
0x00007ffbb5530000 - 0x00007ffbb554c000     E:\jdk8\jre\bin\net.dll
0x00007ffbd3390000 - 0x00007ffbd33fa000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x00007ffb99d40000 - 0x00007ffb99ece000     E:\Mathematica\SystemFiles\Links\JLink\SystemFiles\Libraries\Windows-x86-64\JLinkNativeLibrary.dll
0x00007ffbd61a0000 - 0x00007ffbd627a000     C:\Windows\System32\COMDLG32.dll
0x00007ffbb7ec0000 - 0x00007ffbb7ed7000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x00007ffbd15f0000 - 0x00007ffbd168e000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x00007ffbb7ea0000 - 0x00007ffbb7ebb000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x00007ffbb7e80000 - 0x00007ffbb7e95000     C:\Windows\system32\wshbth.dll
0x00007ffbcf630000 - 0x00007ffbcf64d000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x00007ffbd3030000 - 0x00007ffbd306b000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x00007ffbd6280000 - 0x00007ffbd6395000     C:\Windows\System32\MSCTF.dll
0x00007ffbd63a0000 - 0x00007ffbd646d000     C:\Windows\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x00007ffbd3070000 - 0x00007ffbd313b000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll
0x00007ffbd5620000 - 0x00007ffbd5628000     C:\Windows\System32\NSI.dll
0x00007ffbb7140000 - 0x00007ffbb7152000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x0000000061320000 - 0x0000000061346000     C:\Program Files\Bonjour\mdnsNSP.dll
0x00007ffbcc140000 - 0x00007ffbcc1c0000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x00007ffbd44b0000 - 0x00007ffbd44d7000     C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll
0x00007ffbcc220000 - 0x00007ffbcc22a000     C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll
0x00007ffbd3fc0000 - 0x00007ffbd4042000     C:\Windows\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x00007ffbc9f50000 - 0x00007ffbca049000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\textinputframework.dll
0x00007ffbd0dc0000 - 0x00007ffbd111e000     C:\Windows\System32\CoreUIComponents.dll
0x00007ffbd1120000 - 0x00007ffbd1212000     C:\Windows\System32\CoreMessaging.dll
0x00007ffbd28d0000 - 0x00007ffbd2903000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntmarta.dll
0x00007ffbcfa60000 - 0x00007ffbcfbb4000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wintypes.dll
0x00007ffbd5c10000 - 0x00007ffbd5d3a000     C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll
0x00007ffbd5d40000 - 0x00007ffbd5de9000     C:\Windows\System32\clbcatq.dll
0x00007ffba17c0000 - 0x00007ffba19b4000     C:\Windows\system32\SogouTSF.ime
0x00007ffbc74f0000 - 0x00007ffbc74f7000     C:\Windows\system32\MSIMG32.dll
0x00007ffba0f20000 - 0x00007ffba17bf000     C:\Windows\system32\SogouPy.ime
0x00007ffbcc550000 - 0x00007ffbcc65a000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINHTTP.dll
0x00007ffbbf280000 - 0x00007ffbbf2e6000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\OLEACC.dll
0x0000000010000000 - 0x000000001011e000     E:\SogouInput\10.4.0.4620\Resource.dll
0x00007ffbd1700000 - 0x00007ffbd172f000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dwmapi.dll
0x00007ffb98e00000 - 0x00007ffb9906a000     E:\SogouInput\Components\PicFace\1.1.0.1879\PicFace64.dll
0x00007ffbc1290000 - 0x00007ffbc133c000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\TextShaping.dll
0x00007ffbb30c0000 - 0x00007ffbb326e000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DUI70.dll
0x00007ffb99b90000 - 0x00007ffb99c25000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DUser.dll
0x00007ffbac190000 - 0x00007ffbac1b4000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\edputil.dll
0x00007ffbac230000 - 0x00007ffbac450000     C:\Windows\system32\explorerframe.dll
0x00007ffbce4e0000 - 0x00007ffbce694000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WindowsCodecs.dll
0x00007ffbac1c0000 - 0x00007ffbac226000     C:\Windows\System32\thumbcache.dll
0x00007ffbce2d0000 - 0x00007ffbce370000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\policymanager.dll
0x00007ffbd2d30000 - 0x00007ffbd2dba000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\msvcp110_win.dll
0x00007ffbac450000 - 0x00007ffbac48e000     C:\Windows\system32\dataexchange.dll
0x00007ffbd0020000 - 0x00007ffbd0283000     C:\Windows\system32\d3d11.dll
0x00007ffbd0850000 - 0x00007ffbd0a34000     C:\Windows\system32\dcomp.dll
0x00007ffbd24d0000 - 0x00007ffbd25c3000     C:\Windows\system32\dxgi.dll
0x00007ffbce820000 - 0x00007ffbcea20000     C:\Windows\system32\twinapi.appcore.dll
0x00007ffbcf650000 - 0x00007ffbcf746000     C:\Windows\System32\PROPSYS.dll
0x00007ffbd4050000 - 0x00007ffbd409e000     C:\Windows\System32\CFGMGR32.dll
0x00007ffba90e0000 - 0x00007ffba93d5000     C:\Windows\System32\uiautomationcore.dll
0x00007ffbd39e0000 - 0x00007ffbd3a82000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sxs.dll
0x00007ffbaa940000 - 0x00007ffbaa94d000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\atlthunk.dll
0x00007ffbbc3b0000 - 0x00007ffbbc456000     C:\Windows\System32\StructuredQuery.dll
0x00007ffba50b0000 - 0x00007ffba5111000     C:\Windows\System32\Windows.FileExplorer.Common.dll
0x00007ffbc7f60000 - 0x00007ffbc8211000     C:\Windows\System32\iertutil.dll
0x00007ffbaf100000 - 0x00007ffbaf246000     C:\Windows\System32\Windows.StateRepositoryPS.dll
0x00007ffba4c90000 - 0x00007ffba4d56000     C:\Windows\system32\Windows.Storage.Search.dll
0x00007ffbaa8e0000 - 0x00007ffbaa8e9000     C:\Windows\system32\IconCodecService.dll
0x00007ffbb8cf0000 - 0x00007ffbb8d0d000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MPR.dll
0x00007ffbd5770000 - 0x00007ffbd57e9000     C:\Windows\System32\coml2.dll
0x00007ffbbc8f0000 - 0x00007ffbbc8fb000     C:\Windows\System32\drprov.dll
0x00007ffbd2a40000 - 0x00007ffbd2a9a000     C:\Windows\System32\WINSTA.dll
0x00007ffbba130000 - 0x00007ffbba14f000     C:\Windows\System32\ntlanman.dll
0x00007ffbba0d0000 - 0x00007ffbba0ee000     C:\Windows\System32\davclnt.dll
0x00007ffbbc650000 - 0x00007ffbbc65d000     C:\Windows\System32\DAVHLPR.dll
0x00007ffbd2dc0000 - 0x00007ffbd2dd9000     C:\Windows\System32\wkscli.dll
0x00007ffbb4ec0000 - 0x00007ffbb4ecd000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\LINKINFO.dll
0x00007ffbb7120000 - 0x00007ffbb7132000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cscapi.dll
0x00007ffbd3140000 - 0x00007ffbd314c000     C:\Windows\System32\netutils.dll
0x00007ffbd1430000 - 0x00007ffbd14c0000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\apphelp.dll
0x00007ffbbc240000 - 0x00007ffbbc296000     C:\Windows\System32\dlnashext.dll
0x00007ffbb3660000 - 0x00007ffbb36c4000     C:\Windows\System32\PlayToDevice.dll
0x00007ffbbab30000 - 0x00007ffbbab50000     C:\Windows\System32\DevDispItemProvider.dll
0x00007ffbab8a0000 - 0x00007ffbab91d000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntshrui.dll
0x00007ffbd3a90000 - 0x00007ffbd3ac2000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll
0x00007ffbc7900000 - 0x00007ffbc7928000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\srvcli.dll
0x00007ffbcdaa0000 - 0x00007ffbcdb25000     C:\Windows\System32\MMDevApi.dll
0x00007ffbd3980000 - 0x00007ffbd39ac000     C:\Windows\System32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x00007ffbbf630000 - 0x00007ffbbf7d5000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.19041.1706_none_919e8e54cc8d4ca1\gdiplus.dll
0x00007ffbce3c0000 - 0x00007ffbce463000     C:\Windows\System32\PortableDeviceApi.dll
0x00007ffbd49b0000 - 0x00007ffbd4e1f000     C:\Windows\System32\SETUPAPI.dll
0x00007ffbd3bd0000 - 0x00007ffbd3c37000     C:\Windows\System32\WINTRUST.dll
0x00007ffbd41b0000 - 0x00007ffbd4306000     C:\Windows\System32\CRYPT32.dll
0x00007ffbd37c0000 - 0x00007ffbd37d2000     C:\Windows\System32\MSASN1.dll
0x00007ffbbcdd0000 - 0x00007ffbbce07000     C:\Windows\System32\EhStorShell.dll
0x00007ffbb4330000 - 0x00007ffbb4356000     C:\Windows\System32\EhStorAPI.dll
0x00007ffbcf900000 - 0x00007ffbcf914000     C:\Windows\System32\WTSAPI32.dll
0x00007ffbcdd90000 - 0x00007ffbcde31000     C:\Windows\System32\ActXPrxy.dll
0x00007ffbaa950000 - 0x00007ffbaabb3000     E:\BaiduNetdisk\YunShellExtV164.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Djava.library.path=E:\Mathematica\SystemFiles\Links\JLink\SystemFiles\Libraries\Windows-x86-64 -javaagent:E:\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=64842:E:\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.2\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
java_command: SolveDE
java_class_path (initial): E:\jdk8\jre\lib\charsets.jar;E:\jdk8\jre\lib\deploy.jar;E:\jdk8\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;E:\jdk8\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;E:\jdk8\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;E:\jdk8\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;E:\jdk8\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;E:\jdk8\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;E:\jdk8\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;E:\jdk8\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;E:\jdk8\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;E:\jdk8\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;E:\jdk8\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;E:\jdk8\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;E:\jdk8\jre\lib\javaws.jar;E:\jdk8\jre\lib\jce.jar;E:\jdk8\jre\lib\jfr.jar;E:\jdk8\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;E:\jdk8\jre\lib\jsse.jar;E:\jdk8\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;E:\jdk8\jre\lib\plugin.jar;E:\jdk8\jre\lib\resources.jar;E:\jdk8\jre\lib\rt.jar;E:\idea_pro\DE-Solutions\out\production\DE-Solutions;E:\Mathematica\SystemFiles\Links\JLink\JLink.jar;E:\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=E:\jdk8
PATH=E:\vmware\bin\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;E:\Nodejs\;E:\Git\cmd;E:\jdk8\bin;E:\mysql-8.0.26-winx64\bin;E:\xftp\;E:\python3\Scripts;E:\python3;E:\Anaconda;E:\xshell\;E:\gradle-7.4.2\bin;E:\Golang\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Wolfram Research\WolframScript\;C:\Users\niaomama\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\niaomama\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\niaomama\go\bin
USERNAME=niaomama
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=AMD64 Family 25 Model 33 Stepping 0, AuthenticAMD



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 10 , 64 bit Build 19041 (10.0.19041.1806)

CPU:total 12 (initial active 12) (12 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 25 model 33 stepping 0, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, mmxext, 3dnowpref, lzcnt, sse4a, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv, bmi1

Memory: 4k page, physical 16701676k(9780936k free), swap 25614572k(15006592k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.341-b10) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_341-b10), built on Jun 16 2022 15:51:07 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 15.9 (VS2017)

time: Sun Jul 31 19:46:38 2022
timezone: AMD64 Family 25 Model 33 Stepping 0, AuthenticAMD
elapsed time: 2.340041 seconds (0d 0h 0m 2s)
```

Comment: Using MMA without Java your `DSolve` returns `{{y->Function[{x},-((Sqrt[x]*Sqrt[2+5*x^5*C[1]])/Sqrt[5])]}, {y->Function[{x},(Sqrt[x]*Sqrt[2+5*x^5*C[1]])/Sqrt[5]]}}` because no ic is included and `DSolve[{y'[t]==y[t]+t,y[0]==1},y,t]` returns
`{{y->Function[{t},-1+2 E^t-t]}}` and your `NDSolve[...]][[1,1]];Table[Evaluate[y[x]/.odes],{x,0,10000,1000}]` returns `{1.,3.94*^434,7.76*^868,1.53*^1303,3.01*^1737,5.94*^2171,1.17*^2606,2.30*^3040,4.54*^3474,8.94*^3908,1.76*^4343}` along with string of warning/errors that the numbers are SO big that precision is being lost. Any of those problems help you

Comment: `-1+2 E^10000-10000` is never going to fit in a Java double, even `-1+2 E^1000-1000` won't fit. If you can describe exactly what you want to pass to the Mathematica interface and exactly what you want Mathematica to pass back to the interface then I will try to fiddle with the Mathematica code and see if I can fix that side of things. Are you trying to pass it a double value for `t` and you want back double `y[t]` for that? A really simple concrete example will help me try to figure out what to do for you. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can always try sending/receiving the Mathematica output as a string until you can see what you're receiving.  (Expecting Bill is right about the source of the problem.)